# Question about "print(input("input:\n"))"

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've recently decided to return to python but I found that

```
print(input("input:\n"))
```

returns:

```
input:

3 + 4

7
```

How is this possible? I thought that when you use input() you always get a string.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3, not Python 2?

Comment: Alex has the right idea. `input` in python2 will attempt to evaluate what you type in while `input` in python3 will return a string of whatever is typed in. If you have to use python2, use `raw_input` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior in Python 2.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input):

> `input([prompt])`
>   Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

In Python 3, `input` was removed, and Python 2's `raw_input` was renamed to `input`.

So, make sure you are using the correct Python version, and make sure you are using the appropriate `input`/`raw_input` function depending on which Python version you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I tried provided code and got string "3+7" as result.

This is what the [Python Docs on Input Method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) say

**input([prompt])**

If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, **EOFError** is raised. Example:

```
    >>> s = input('--> ')  
    --> Monty Python's Flying Circus
    >>> s  
    "Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.